# discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: ctx is a required argument that is missing

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
#help command
@client.command()
async def help(prefix, ctx, type_help = "None"):
  author = ctx.message.author
  if type_help == "None":
    embed = discord.Embed(title = "Help Command", value = "Welcome to the Help Command. Look at the various categories the bot has to offer! If there is a <> it is optional! Also if there is a [], that is required. This bot is made by ! bobthefam#6969", color=discord.Colour.blue())
    embed.add_field(name = f"``{prefix}polls``", value = "", inline = False)
  else:
    embed = discord.Embed(title = "Oops", description = "I think you may have misspelled something. Try again")
            
  await ctx.channel.send(author, embed = embed)
```

I get the error in the title. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

from [this](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#commands) page you can see that the actually function doesn't take prefix it's the command that does.

Your code should be has follow:

```py
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@client.command() # !help for invoke the command
async def help(ctx, type_help = "None"):
  author = ctx.message.author
  [...]
```

from the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=bot#discord.ext.commands.Bot.command_prefix) you can make a dynamic prefix by using a callable (just a nice way to say a function ;) ) for the command_prefix variable

something like this I guess:

```py
def my_custom_prefix(bot, message):
  # bot.commands contain all available commands
  matching_command = [command.name for command in bot.commands if command.name in message]
  if matching_command:
     return message.split(matching_command[0])[0]
  return "!" # I guess you need a default prefix in case

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=my_custom_prefix, case_insensitive=True)

@client.command() # {whatever_you_want_by_default_!}help for invoke the command
async def help(ctx, type_help = "None"):
  author = ctx.message.author
  [...]
```

Comment: I have that, but I want to make customizable prefixes.

Comment: @SohamGarg You can change the value of the `command_prefix` property